# Binding with [(ngModel)] an Input of type Date not showing the date

Tags: angular, forms, date

I'm trying to display (Angular 15), in a form, a preset date that I created in the component this way:

```
defaultOpening: Opening = new Opening(1, new Date(), new Date());
ngOnInit() {
    this.HotelModel.openings.push(this.defaultOpening);
}
```

The field is showing correctly in the ngFor loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let opening of HotelModel.openings">
  <td>{{ opening.start | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
  <td>{{ opening.end | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

But show as empty date fields in this loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let opening of HotelModel.openings; let i = index">
  <td><input [(ngModel)]="opening.start" name="startMonth{{i}}" type="date"></td>
  <td><input [(ngModel)]="opening.end" name="startDay{{i}}" type="date"></td>
</tr>
```

Like this:
[image]

Is there a way to show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type="date"` tells the browser to render a date picker instead of a text field and the actual value of the input is just text string with `yyyy-MM-dd` format (see [input type="date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value)), so, for two way binding to work you need to pass a string in the correct format.

You can do as @DEV suggests and do:

```
<input 
    [ngModel]="opening.start | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" 
    (ngModelChange)="opening.start = $event" 
    type="date" 
    name="opening.start"
/>
```

but be mindful that the moment you change the value, instead of an object you will have a string which will need to be converted back to an object. This conversion can happen during the ngModelChange event, just do `opening.start = toDate($event)` where toDate takes a string in `yyyy-MM-dd` format and returns a date.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pipe :

```
<input [ngModel]="opening.start | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="opening.start = $event" type="date" name="opening.start"/>
```